# Why does my Posts page only show a single post when using Thematic?

Tags: customization, homepage

This seems to be a Thematic theme bug becuase if I switch to other themes, everything is working as expected. This is not the first time I created a frontpage using a static page. I made sure I followed this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page. Any idea pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely check this page : http://themeshaper.com/forums/topic/posts-inside-the-pages-and-subpages

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. It's about creating a custom frontpage. My problem is my posts/blog page is showing only one post while my frontpage is working fine.

Comment: I see two things here: Custom Frontpage in WP is just not the feature you expect it to be (this can be experienced from time to time at least for me in support) -or- Thematic is incompatbile with that feature. I doubt that, but in any case, I would checkout the forums of Thematic to find out first place. Probably you can link this here then.

Comment: crosspost ref: http://themeshaper.com/forums/topic/why-does-my-posts-page-only-shows-a-single-post